# finding the number of occurence of a substring in a string

Tags: java

I wanted to find the number of occurence of a substring in a string I implemented following code in java:

```
Pattern mypattern=Pattern.compile("a");
Matcher mymatcher=mypattern.compile("aaaaaa");
int cnt=0;
while(mymatcher.find()){
    cnt++;
)
System.out.println(cnt);
```

But it doesn't work when I want the function to count also the intersecting strings for example I want th e answer to the search of aa in aaaaaa be 5 but the above program will show it 3.How can I do so?

Comment: Perhaps you should find the first occurrence, then start your search for the next occurrence from 1 char after. eg if you find the string first at index 10, start the next search at 11

Comment: Please post the code you're __actually__ using. This posted code neither matches the description, nor compiles.

Comment: Why do you want `5` as an answer when checking how often `aaaaaa` contains `a`? I count 6 occurances and that is also what your code will give as an answer (once i change `mypattern.compile` to `mypattern.matcher` to actually be able to run the code)

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS That's what I meant with code not matching description, because OP talked about "aa", not about "a" like in the code.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS OP meant "find `aa` in `aaaaaa` returns 5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A positive lookahead `(?=(aa))`could be used in the regular expression to handle overlapping matches:

```java
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("(?=(aa))").matcher("aaaaaa").results().count());

// 5
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will give you your desired count of 5 if you are searching for occurrences of *aa* in *aaaaaa*.

```java
Pattern mypattern = Pattern.compile("aa");
Matcher mymatcher = mypattern.matcher("aaaaaa");
int cnt = 0;
int start = 0;
while (mymatcher.find(start)) {
    start = mymatcher.start() + 1;
    cnt++;
}
System.out.println(cnt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Commons Lang library:

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.countMatches(str, subStr));
```

Comment: Are you referring to this [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)?

Comment: Yes, just import StringUtils class: import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;